# reg add saves incorrect value for file association

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, file-association

Run from Admin this code works in Windows XP.

```
set app=ExtrNS.exe
set nam=ExtrNS@
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\%nam%\command" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d """"%CD%\ExtrNS.exe""" """%%1"" /f
```

In Windows 7, the result is not the home directory, but `"C:\Windows\ExtrNS.exe" "%1"`

Answer (score 0):

#### The result is not the home directory, but is "C:\Windows\ExtrNS.exe" "%1"

`%CD%` has the value of the the current directory, which will be the directory from where the batch file is executed.

If you want the user's "Home Directory", use `%UserProfile%` instead of `%CD%`.

---

#### By home I meant where the .exe file is not the user's home directory

The easiest way to do this is to include the path of the .exe file as part of the `app` variable:

```
set app=c:\path_to_appp\ExtrNS.exe
```

- Change `path_to_app` as appropriate for your computer.
- Remove `%CD%\` as it is now not needed.

---

#### Standard (built-in) Environment Variables

- `CD`  - The current directory (string).
- `USERPROFILE` - %SystemDrive%\Users\{username}

  This is equivalent to the $HOME environment variable in Unix/Linux

Source [Windows Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.

Comment: now i got that "C:\Users\n1ke\ExtrNS.exe" "%1" sry my eng, but i mean home where exe file.

Comment: @soft0nut Answer updated.